# Set 2nd row as header column in CSV to datatable conversion

Tags: c#

I am trying to read CSV file and fetch the data in datatable in C#.

I have used the below code, which works fine:

```
public static System.Data.DataTable GetcsvExcelRecords(string csvPath, string CSVFileName)
        {
            string[] workSheetNames = new string[] { };  
            System.Data.DataTable dtExcelData = new System.Data.DataTable();
            string SourceConstr  = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + csvPath + "';Extended Properties='Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'";

            using (OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(SourceConstr))
            {
                excelConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                excelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + CSVFileName + "]", excelConn);
                excelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = excelCommand;
                excelDataAdapter.Fill(dtExcelData);
                return dtExcelData;
            }

        }
```

However, I want the 2nd row data to be the header column and then followed by the rows. How to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: May I know if the csv file that you are working on is small or huge? You may guess the size in KB/MB

Comment: File is small. Max size is 100 kb

Answer (score 0):

You can rather use existing libraries instead of reinventing (reimplementing)... I have heard that [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) might be of some use.

On any case, we like trying out something before realizing the need for library. In such a case...

If csv file size is small, you can try something dirty like this... this might sound trivial though.
Note that there is a need for file to be on disk to use OleDbConnection...
Don't forget to delete the file created...

```
public static System.Data.DataTable GetcsvExcelRecords(string csvPath, string CSVFileName)
{
    string modCSVFileName = CreateFileRemovingFirstLine(csvPath, CSVFileName);

    string[] workSheetNames = new string[] { };
    System.Data.DataTable dtExcelData = new System.Data.DataTable();
    string SourceConstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + csvPath + "';Extended Properties='Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'";

    using (OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(SourceConstr))
    {
        excelConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        excelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + modCSVFileName + "]", excelConn);
        excelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = excelCommand;
        excelDataAdapter.Fill(dtExcelData);
        return dtExcelData;
    }
}

private static string CreateFileRemovingFirstLine(string csvPath, string CSVFileName)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(csvPath, CSVFileName);
    string modifiedFileName = CSVFileName.Replace(".csv", "2.csv");
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string headerLine = sr.ReadLine();
        string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        // use the appropriate encoding... for example I am using ASCII
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        // write to file... check for access permission to create file
        FileStream file = new FileStream(Path.Combine(csvPath, modifiedFileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        ms.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
        ms.Close();
    }

    return modifiedFileName;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry, if my question had confused. I want the changes in the datatable, and the not in the file.